# unexpected directive imported by the module please add a @ngmodule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Tried `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` in an attempt to prepare an app for deployment.
I came across an error which I attempted to fix.
The error originally received was

> Type SecondPage in
>   longlocation/second/second.ts is
>   part of the 
>   declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in longlocation/src/app/app.module.ts and 
>               SecondPageModule in longlocation/src/pages/second/second.module.ts!
>   Please 
>               consider moving SecondPage in longlocation/src/pages/second/second.ts to a
>   higher 
>               module that imports AppModule in longlocation/src/app/app.module.ts and 
>               SecondPageModule in longlocation/src/pages/second/second.module.ts.

I removed the mentioned components from

> declarations

as instructed by another stackoverflow answer.

Now I'm getting another error which says

> unexpected directive 'SecondPage' imported by the module 'AppModule'.
>   Please add a @ngmodule annotation

My code is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SecondPage } from '../pages/second/second';
import { SendtextPage } from '../pages/sendtext/sendtext';

import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    //SecondPage,
    //SendtextPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
      SecondPage,
      SendtextPage,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SecondPage,
    SendtextPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    SMS,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

> Ionic Framework : 3.9.2 Ionic App Scripts : 3.2.1 Angular Core :
>   5.2.11 Angular Compiler CLI : 5.2.11 Node : 10.6.0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add them into ``declarations`` and ``entryComponents``

Comment: Why do you have page components in the `imports` array in your app module? Only modules should be declared there.

Comment: It was not originally there. I added it there to remove another error. Which in turn lead to this. The original error is also mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried to add them to both ``declarations`` and ``entryComponents``

Comment: @Abdulrahman That's how the original code was. I get the error "Type SecondPage in /longdirectory/src/pages/second/second.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and SecondPageModule. Please consider moving SecondPage to a higher module that imports AppModule and SecondPageModule".

Comment: @ElaBuwa, Can you provide stackblitz related with the above code?? As Richards pointed out only modules has to be imported inside ```imports``` array and component cannot be declared there..

Answer (score 0):

edit your `second.module.ts` and remove `SecondPage` from declarations 
and leave it on `app.module.ts` if you navigate to it like this :

```
this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage);
```

if you'r navigate to it using :

```
 this.navCtrl.push("SecondPage");
```

you should remove it from `app.module.ts` too